# Differentiability functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f:A\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ and $g:B\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ are differentiable functions on the open sets A, B and $\alpha,\beta$ are constants. Prove that $\alpha f+\beta g:A\cap B\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow R^m$ is differentiable and $\textbf D (\alpha f+\beta g)(x)=\alpha \textbf D f(x)+\beta \textbf D g(x)$

To me, it is quite trivial and I don't know how to work on it. Since f, g are differentiable and $(\alpha f)'=\alpha f'$, same as $\beta g$.

For part b) apply definition of differentiable function  $D(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)=lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{(\alpha f+\beta g)(x+h) -(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)}{h}$ After calculating, I can get the result. I do need know whether I am on the right track or not. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ ($A$ open) is said to be differentiable at $x \in A$ if there exists a linear transformation, denoted by $Df(x)$ such that:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\left \| f(x+h)-f(x)-(Df(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}=0$$

Note that $Df(x)$ is **function** between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. Furthermore, $Df(x)$ is the only linear transformation which verifies the limit above.

So in order to prove that $D(\alpha f + \beta g)=\alpha Df(x) + \beta Dg(x)$ it suffices to prove that:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\left \| (\alpha f + \beta g)(x+h)-(\alpha f + \beta g)(x)-(\alpha Df(x)+ \beta Dg(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}=0$$

Since then, by uniqueness, $D(\alpha f + \beta g)=\alpha Df(x) + \beta Dg(x)$. This also proves that $\alpha f + \beta g$ is differentiable at $x \in A \cap B$ since we've found a linear transformation ($\alpha Df(x) + \beta Dg(x)$) which verifies the limit in the definition.

Now observe that, by the triangle inequality

$$\lim_{h \to 0}{\left \| (\alpha f + \beta g)(x+h)-(\alpha f + \beta g)(x)-(\alpha Df(x)+ \beta Dg(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}≤\lim_{h \to 0}\left ({\left \| \alpha f (x+h)-\alpha f (x)-\alpha (Df(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}+{\left \| \beta g(x+h)-\beta g(x)-\beta (Dg(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|} \right )=\lim_{h \to 0}\left (|\alpha|{\left \| f (x+h)-f (x)-(Df(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}+|\beta|{\left \| g(x+h)-g(x)-(Dg(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|} \right )= \quad |\alpha|\lim_{h \to 0}{\left \| f (x+h)-f (x)-(Df(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}+|\beta|\lim_{h\to 0}{\left \| g(x+h)-g(x)-(Dg(x))(h) \right \| \over \left \| h \right \|}=0+0=0$$